# Filter the duplicate rows of a pandas dataframe, keeping rows with the latest date only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```py
d = {'title':['GrownUps', 'Toy Story', 'Toy Story', 'Avatar', 'Avatar', 'Avatar'], 'year': [2012, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2006, 2010]}
dataset=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

From the dataframe above I want to locate and the duplicate movie title (i.e Toy Story, Avatar). To do so, I use the following code:

```py
dataset[dataset.duplicated(subset=['title'],keep=False)]
```

From the rows returned I would like to keep per duplicate movie the most recent one (e.g the maximum of the column `year`) and store to a list the indexes of the rows not having the maximum year so I can filter them from the initial dataset.

So my final dataset should look like this:

```py
d = {'title':['GrownUps', 'Toy Story', 'Avatar'], 'year': [2012, 2000, 2010]}
dataset=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

*I kept only Toy Story of 2000 instead of 1995, and Avatar of year 2010 not 2005 or 2006*

This could be very useful if someone wants to use a different aggregate rather than `max()`, like `mean()`, `sum()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can sort by ascending order of "year", then drop duplicates on "title" keeping the last row (since that has the latest year), then restoring the original ordering of rows:

```
df.sort_values('year').drop_duplicates('title', keep='last').sort_index()

       title  year
0   GrownUps  2012
2  Toy Story  2000
5     Avatar  2010
```

This avoids a groupBy operation (which is relatively slower) and  maintains the original ordering of rows.